# Column naming in tables that break into two columns

Tags: tables, wrapping

I have a design for a monitoring screen that shows only two pieces of information per row:

- Name
- Status

[image]

The user will not be able to interact with the UI because it will be shown on a TV in a room for status tracking. Because of this, in case when there are more entries that can fit into the screen height, instead of allowing the page to scroll the table breaks into two columns.

[image]

My question is:

Does it make sense to not repeat the table header labels since the user can associate the far left with “module” and far right with “status”?

My assumption is that the user will not have any problems reading the table that breaks into two columns without the table header also breaking the same way. Especially because there is clearly a gap between the two columns.

Comment: how long are the values? how big could the tv screens get? I ask because the module and the status have no differentiation. I'm wondering if you have certain statuses that a user should pay attention to, and use maybe some graphic treatment to attract their attention.

Comment: Are the headers even necessary? Seems like the meaning is obvious with only two values per item.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an obvious need to repeat it for both the columns. Nonetheless, I would advise against the layout of labels in your 2 column layout - I would expect better readability with the label assigned to the first column, for these reasons:

- clearer transfer from 1 to 2 column view
- easier matching of labels to items
- better understanding that column 1 continues into column 2

Like this:

[image]